# Apex:Component refresh on page rerender

Tags: salesforce, reload, visualforce, apex, rerender

again, lovely people.

Having an issue with getting an apex:component to refresh when the page reloads, and I can't seem to figure out what to do with it.

We've tried everything from putting the component in an outputPanel and adding that to the rerender attribute, reloading the entire page with an oncomplete, using the window.reload (something like that) function, and even tried forcing a reload with setTimeout.

While I'm able to get the entire page itself to reload, the component never does until you actually go up and click the "refresh" button on the browser.

A demo of the code is below:

```
<apex:page controller="myController" id="thePage" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHTMLTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" action="{!onStart}">
    <apex:composition template="myTemplate">
        <apex:define name="header">
            <c:myHeader fixed="true"  language="{!langPref}" filling="true" timeout="true" /> <!--appStatus="{!app.App_Status__c}"-->
        </apex:define>

        <apex:define name="sidebar" >
            <c:mySidebar id="theSidebar" applicationCurrentStage="{!currentStage}" applicationMaxStage="{!app.Application_Stage__c}" stages="{!appPagesMetadata}" memberSegmentedStages="{!memberSegmentedStages}" stagesToInvalidate="{!stagesToInvalidate}" currentMemberIndex="{!memberIndex}" members="{!members}" application="{!app}"/>
        </apex:define>

        <apex:define name="contents">
            <p>There's totally some stuff in here.</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="{!$Label.Save_Progress}" rerender="thePage" rendered="{!app.Application_Stage__c==NEW_STAGE && !guestUser}" oncomplete="myJS.afterSave({!isSaved},false);" status="blockStatus" />
                        <!--Functionality to Save and go Next-->
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAndNext}" value="{!IF(previousStage==app.Application_Stage__c||app.Application_Stage__c==NEW_STAGE,$Label.Save_Next_btn ,$Label.Save_Progress)}" rerender="theForm" oncomplete="myJS.afterSave({!isSaved},true);" status="blockStatus" rendered="{!NOT(guestUser) || NOT(captchaEnabled)}" />
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!verifyCaptcha}" value="{!IF(previousStage==app.Application_Stage__c||app.Application_Stage__c==NEW_STAGE,$Label.Save_Next_btn,$Label.Save_Progress)}" rerender="thePage" oncomplete="myJS.afterSave({!isSaved},true);" status="blockStatus" rendered="{!guestUser && captchaEnabled}" />
                        <apex:actionFunction action="{!nextPage}" name="nextPage" status="blockStatus" />
                        <!--Functionality to Go To Page based on Sidebar preference-->
                        <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="true">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="fastRerenderPanel" />
                            <apex:actionFunction action="{!findPage}" name="goToPage" status="blockStatus" reRender="fastRerenderPanel" oncomplete="redirectToPage();">
                                <apex:param name="goToPage" id="goToPage" assignTo="{!goToPage}" value="" />
                                <apex:param name="memberIndexNavigation" id="memberIndexNavigation" assignTo="{!memberIndex}" value="" />

                            </apex:actionFunction>
                            <apex:actionFunction action="{!redirectToPage}" name="redirectToPage" status="blockStatus" />
                        </apex:actionRegion>

                        <apex:actionStatus id="blockStatus" onstart="myJS.blockScreen();" onstop="myJS.unblockScreen();" />
                    </div>

                </div>

        </apex:define>
    </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks again, everyone.

Comment: I would like to see the code. At least the most important parts. Maybe this helps

Comment: Added some dummy code for you.

For all intents and purposes, clicking save should re-render the entire page, including the component, but it doesn't. :/